# Call remote sh script from local sh file

Tags: bash, ssh, centos

I have a problem with running sh scripts on CentOS which calls remote sh file. On user@host1 I have start.sh file with next command inside

```
NODE1_SSH_PATH=user@host2
PROGRAM_HOME=/home/user/app

ssh $NODE1_SSH_PATH $PROGRAM_HOME/bin/run.sh > start.log
```

Result of this script is next:

```
bash: /home/user/app/bin/run.sh: Permission denied
```

I tried run this script with chmod like this:

```
ssh $NODE1_SSH_PATH chmod u+x $PROGRAM_HOME/bin/run.sh > start.log
```

But in this case I have't got any result, log file is empty to. Could someone help me to slow this I hope simple task?

Comment: `chmod u+x` is something you do once, then try running it again as you did originally. `chmod` does NOT execute the script.

Comment: what is output of : ssh $NODE1_SSH_PATH ls -l $PROGRAM_HOME/bin/run.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe /home/user/app/bin/run.sh is not executable.

try this

```
ssh $NODE1_SSH_PATH /bin/bash $PROGRAM_HOME/bin/run.sh > start.log
```

Comment: Thanks Tiago, you answer is really helpful but I faced with other issue in my script, now I can run remote shell file, but this running locks all other commands, for example I have in the same sh file other call on other node ssh $NODE2_SSH_PATH /bin/bash $PROGRAM_HOME/bin/run.sh > start.log and runner can't reach this line.

Comment: @Maryan I would need more details on what you're trying to do. I could suggest to put this line in the background but it may not be safe to do so. I'd better know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Tiago, your first answer has everything I need, my comment was result of my own mistake. Thank you, I said it's simple issue :) I don't know why but this script works on Ubuntu, without /bin/bash but needs it on CentOS.